# Where can I purchase .app TLD?

Tags: dns, appdomain, domain-name, tld, .app

Where can I purchase a .app Top Level Domain (TLD)?

I've gone to Network Solutions, GoDaddy, etc and can't find someone who is selling .app domains (e.g. http://example.app).

Comment: Give this a read - http://appdomain.org/

Comment: https://www.registry.google/

Comment: The official site is https://get.app

Comment: @D.Shawley, Site down...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nowhere.  The timeline given out by ICANN projects the new gTLDs won't be available until the beginning of 2013:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain#New_top-level_domains

You will know when they are operational because they will appear on IANA's website:

http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/

More info on gTLDs as well:

http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/

Update: The .app top level domain is available and you can purchase your domain by visiting https://get.app/. All domains require HTTPS as the .app top level domain is HSTS preloaded.

Answer (score 28):

Little update for everyone that is interested...

> Launch details for .app
>   We are currently in the process of launching our fourth open top-level domain, .app, a more secure domain for apps. From games to news to education to business, .app is the perfect home to promote apps on the web. The .app domain is a great place to showcase a unique and trustworthy destination. If you’re interested in carrying .app domains, you can download our RRA here.

```
Here are the important dates to be aware of in 2018:

Mar 29 - May 1: Trademark holders can register .app domains (known as the "Sunrise" period).
May 1 - May 8: Anyone can register available .app domains for an extra fee (known as the "Early Access" period).
May 8 and onwards: Anyone can register available .app domains (known as “General Availability").
Please note that a claims period will run indefinitely, during which trademark owners will receive notification when their marks are registered as domains.

For now we will be exclusively focusing on launching .app. We are continuing to work on plans for .dev, which shall be launched at a future time. Stay tuned for more details if you’re interested in carrying .dev!
```

**3rd of February 2017 UPDATE**

```
.APP, coming soon

We're currently working on plans for .APP

If you’re an ICANN Accredited Domain Registrar click here to request more information

If you manage an app store for a mobile operating system, please click here to request more information about becoming a qualified partner for .APP. Criteria for being a qualified partner are listed in the contact form and may enable app stores to promote .APP to their developers, and potentially partner on discounts and/or limited registration periods.
```

Taken straight from Google's own https://www.registry.google/

**5th of January 2017 UPDATE**

Little update, almost two years later and still no news. Google seem to keep the .app to themselves, to protect their Play Store.

**26th of February 2015 UPDATE**

There we go. The auction is over. Google won it for a staggering $25 million! They will now have to decide what to do with it.

Source: https://gtldresult.icann.org/application-result/applicationstatus/auctionresults

**23rd of February 2015 UPDATE**

In two days, the auction for the .app TLD will finally happen. That means that the .app domain names should be available in the coming months. Once a company has won the auction, it will make sure to make the domain names available as soon as possible to start earning money. This is the final step that is holding back this whole process.

Source: http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/auctions

Comment: So Google has won but Where can we pre-register? There seems to be many scam sites out there.

Comment: Nowhere. Don't get fooled. You can't pre-register yet.

Comment: One year later and still no way to get the domain.

Comment: Still no way. Looks like it was only purchased by google to protect the google play app store. Otherwise someone could easily build an app search engine and kill the google profits. Shame on you. Should be sued for cyber squatting.

Comment: Look here for the latest from Google https://www.registry.google/

Comment: A Google search for "[site:app](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:app&filter=0)" shows as of now there are 5 ".app" domains set up: nic.app, domaintest.app, adminer.app, demo.app and whois.nic.app

Comment: April 2018 update: `.APP` is becoming live. " Here are the important dates to be aware of in 2018:

    Mar 29 - May 1: Trademark holders can register .app domains (known as the "Sunrise" period).
    May 1 - May 8: Anyone can register available .app domains for an extra fee (known as the "Early Access" period).
    May 8 and onwards: Anyone can register available .app domains (known as “General Availability")."

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, Where do you suggest is a good place to register? Namecheap?

Comment: @Pacerier I can not say, for at least two reasons: generally this is highly subjective (choices will depend on many constraints that each one values differently), and in this particular case I am obviously biased since I am working in this business right now. You can now find on Google website the list of companies accredited for .APP, including during the EAP period (this week, with higher prices): https://www.registry.google/about/register.html (click on the .APP image)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, I mean which do you use to buy your (or your friend's) .app domain?

Comment: @BenJ, I see that there's 400 now. But is there a better, more official way to get the full list?

Answer (score 11):

You can't register the .APP, even today, more than a year later.

But what you can do, is to watch who will become the .APP registry (who will operate the .APP database).

Several organizations and companies applied to be the registry, you can find it on the ICANN's website at

https://gtldresult.icann.org/application-result/applicationstatus/viewstatus

(The .APP was the most applied for top-level domain, FYI.)

Here on my website, https://www.domainosity.com/domains/app/, you can see the information in more convenient way, also there is syndicated news about the .APP, 
also you can see links to information about the applicants. Good idea may be to subscribe to their social network updates.

If you watch how the situation develops (who will become the registry finally) you will be ready to get the domain as soon as it is possible (and therefore have greatest chance to catch the desired name).

Comment: Has the situation changed since the posting of this answer?

Comment: @MjrKusanagi, Not yet. http://www.quora.com/When-will-app-domains-be-available-for-purchase

Comment: It’s 2015 and you still can’t buy them. Thanks ICANN.

Comment: @Miroslav, Seems like Google has won the bid for $25m. Where can we pre-register?

Comment: @Pacerier yes, I suppose you will be able to register it at https://domains.google.com

Comment: Nice, it's been a whole year and they're still taking their time.

Answer (score 4):

**July 31st Update**

The `.app` gtld was the most highly contended of all the gtlds. At the time of writing it has not yet become eligible to enter auction. This is pretty much key in determining when it will reach the market.

Here are some of the "Not Yet Eligible To Enter An Auction" New gTLDs that will most likely be auctioned after March 2015:

> .Food, .Gay, .Blog, .Radio, .App, .Home, .Hotel, .Cloud, News, .Art,
>   Music, .Movie, Store, .Wine, Search, .Kids/.Kid, .Car/Cars,
>   .Sport/.Sports, .Game/Games and .Web/.Webs.